# Dictation: computer speaks, learner writes

Tags: android, text-processing, educational, text, voice

I am wondering whether there is any software on the Android Google Play store that does the following:

- Text is read out
- The software waits for the text that is read out to be written at the keyboard. This allows children to get used to recognizing the letters for any given word.
- The software turns text prediction on the keyboard off, so that the user really learns to write, if this is more helpful.
- The reading voice either carries on, or waits for the user. They may even accelerate in bits past the user's typing screen to get them to write faster.
- Optionally, it is possible to use a calligraphy keyboard, where letters are written calligraphically in a way that they overlap each other when written on the keyboard, and input.
- Optionally, the text may contain math, and the user might want to switch to an Ams latex keyboard off it exists when math is too be typed, but this would be done by the software.
- Ideally, the user could also upload the text to be read out and traced out on the keyboard, into the program.
- Hand strain could be a problem, and the correct position to sit and gold the phone could be suggested, e.g., visually.
- The program could display mistakes and a score based on speed and accuracy at the end.
- AI could be involved in asking the user for a summary and seeing how good the summary is at the end
- Sessions (with, all the session text) could be saved

This would be nice.

Has this been done?

Is anyone willing to implement this?

Where can I find such software for Android?

I am not aware of any software that implements this at the current moment, and, if it were available, it would be nice

Dictations are good for learners to learn how to write and spell, as well as for summarizing text, and, retaining it in the mind

Thanks.